# U-SQL Query Optimizer behavior

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Okay, here is what am doing. I have a U-SQL script which does the following.

Step 1. INSERT a record into a txn table 'A' say "PROCESSING STARTED", recording the start of Step 2.
Step 2. Extract from a file 
Step 3. Insert into table 'B' using the rowset from Step 2.
Step 4. INSERT a record into a txn table 'A' say "PROCESSING FINISHED", recording the successful execution of Step 2.

When I coded the above I was hoping above steps will execute in the mentioned order. To my surprise it was not, when I closely looked into the Algebra I came to understand that query optimizer shuffled all my tasks and it runs it as below.

1. All Extract
2. All Splits, Aggregates, Partitions
3. All Writes (if you notice there are 2 tables am inserting into)

So the question I have here is how do I ensure that Step 2, Step 3 executes only after Step 1 ? I am not bothered about Step 4 as of now. I could possibly run as below too but I was hoping there would be some other options.
Job 1 (Step 1)
Job 2 (Step 2, 3)
Job 3 (Step 4)

Pls can you help out ?

Answer (score 2):

U-SQL is designed to optimize your query so it can be scaled out across multiple nodes - resulting in efficient execution of your query. What you are observing is by design, in your code, since there is no dependency between Steps 1 and 2, there is an opportunity for parallelizing their execution.

One option I can think of for you to execute them in a certain sequence is to introduce a dependency on a result from Step 1 in Step 2.

Having said that, if you are looking at a sequential execution pattern, I'm curious as to why you chose U-SQL (which is designed for massively parallized applications).

Comment: Step 2, Step 3 is where I need the parallelism where am trying to crunch data in TB's. Step 1, Step 4 are simple INSERT queries to log the success of Step 2, Step 3. So I need that dependency, saying so I can have a ADF pipeline setup up for this. Was that your suggestion too ?

Comment: Hi Shiva, looks like you want to do a transaction log of your query execution, is that right? I was suggesting that you look for a particular cue for success and start the next step. If insert is successful, do Step 2. if Step 2 is successful, do step 3. E.g. if numRowsInserted == 1, do Step 2. If extraction yielded non 0 amount of rows, do Step 3.

Comment: Exactly. I am quite aware of how to apply predicates for Insert, Select. However am not sure if I can base my Extract, Output on a condition. Like lets say if Step 1 has successfully inserted 1 record then Extract if not don't Extract. Do you have pseudo code handy ?

Comment: Shiva, we have a conditional execution feature on the roadmap that would possibly help your scenario, please do vote on http://aka.ms/ifinusql or create a feedback.

My suggestion in the meantime was something along the lines described below, please note that this is NOT a U-SQL pattern, but more of a workaround.

//Execute step 1

result = //Check if step 1 executed. E.g. if Step 1 was insert, do a select to see if insert was successful.

//Step 2
step2 = <statement involving result as one of hte rowsets you are manipulating, this ensures that this will execute after Step 2.

Comment: Got you. Saying so I do see a limitation of querying on a table on which I had performed a DML in the same U-SQL script :(

Comment: In general, I would suggest that you use ADF or Powershell to orchestrate the sequential steps and keep each script to one step.